# Wrong file size in File Object on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm checking the file size of the files added via the `<input />` html element in my Nextjs project.

It's working pretty fine on desktop.
But now I've tested it on mobile (iOS) and the internal file picker of the iOS is previewing a different file size than the `file[0].size` object in JavaScript.

Background is, that I'm not uploading files bigger than 5MB to the server ([Vercel](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-bypass-vercel-5mb-body-size-limit-serverless-functions) has a strict 5MB payload limit) - so I'm testing for `file[0].size < maxFileSize`.

If I'm selecting a 6,7MB picture on my phone, the `file[0].size is 4856162` (and not 6,7x1024x1024 = 7025459)  and therefore below my `5242880` limit. But the server is now throwing errors, because the payload is above 5MB.

Are there any possibilities to get the "true" file size of iOS images in JS?

EDIT:

Screenshot of the iOS file browser, which shows that this image has for example 7,1MB
[image]

Screenshot of the safari log on iOS, which shows the logged file.size and the maxFileSize:
[image]

@brc-dd: Thanks for your suggestion, for now I'll just catch the 413 response from the server - but this is nonetheless a strange behaviour

Comment: Which browser (version) are you using? Safari v<10 don't/partially support File API. FWIW, you can always add a fallback check to handle the case of 413 status code. Also, 5MB is 5e6 bytes not 5242880 bytes.

Comment: @tobysas your case does not make sense. When you select a 6.7MB file, it's obviously larger than 5MB. Why do you still believe that it will be smaller than 5MB? Can you show us the codes that create the `file[0]` object?

Comment: @Raptor The OP wants to say that when they are uploading 6.7MB file, `file[0].size` is giving 4856162 which is not correct. Now since the check is simply a `file[0].size < maxFileSize`, the validation is passing and the request is being sent, which for obvious reasons will be rejected by Vercel.

Comment: @brc-dd thanks for your suggestion, for now i'll go with catching the response. Your question with the browser: it happens in all tested browsers (latest brave for ios, latest safari for ios). Added some screenshot for "proof" aswell.